# com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I got an error when I ran a mapreduce job.

```
Failed on local exception: 
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException:Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.;
Host Details : local host is: "hadoop0/10.2.4.9"; destination host is: "0.0.0.0":10020;
```

My /etc/hosts is configured correctly, and all of the configuration files such as hdfs-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, core-site.xml and mapred-site.xml should be fine because I used this code in another cluster before.

The HDFS is fine, and I can put file to HDFS.

Do you know what's wrong?

Following is the error stack:

```
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details : local host is: "hadoop0/10.2.4.9"; destination host is: "0.0.0.0":10020; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getTaskCompletionEvents(ClientServiceDelegate.java:386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getTaskCompletionEvents(YARNRunner.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$5.run(Job.java:668)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$5.run(Job.java:665)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getTaskCompletionEvents(Job.java:665)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.monitorAndPrintJob(Job.java:1366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details : local host is: "hadoop0/10.2.4.9"; destination host is: "0.0.0.0":10020; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.getTaskAttemptCompletionEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.impl.pb.client.MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getTaskAttemptCompletionEvents(MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:320)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidEndTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:94)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.checkLastTagWas(CodedInputStream.java:124)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:202)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:241)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:253)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:259)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.parseDelimitedFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:2364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1055)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:949)
```